# Как получить название ячейки JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Собственно код:

```
"1": {
    "username": "Игрок"
}
```

Как из него получить название ячейки? (Т.е. цифру 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var str = '{"1": [{"username": "Игрок"}]}';
    var event = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(Object.keys(event));
```

Вот ссылка которые Вам будут полезные при работе с JSON

> [JSON и как его "едят"](https://learn.javascript.ru/json)

А вот ответ на Ваш вопрос:

> [Документация по Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var obj = {
  "1": {
    "username": "Игрок"
  }
};
var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
console.log(key, typeof key);
```

Comment: Вывод у меня: `1 string`.  Я просил вывести название. Т.е. `obj`